# Кнопка "возврат" с сохранением состояния запроса api. Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать возврат к элементу(кнопке) по который кликнул.
Суть такая: Есть две страница - главная со списком элементов и страница подробного описания. они сделаны с помощью react-router. 
На странице со списком формируется api запроса, который отдает 20ть элементов. далее когда доходим конца списка, обновляется api запрос - подгружаются еще 20ть элементов, ну и т.д
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По клику на кнопку(I choose you), мы попадаем на страницу с подробным описанием. Соответственно на странице с подробным описанием  есть кнопочка "назад", по нажатию на которую я хочу вернуться назад) Вот я хочу вернуться назад к элементу по которому кликал. Сейчас же по нажатию на кнопку "назад", при возврате на главную страницу происходит api запрос с нуля.
Кнопка "назад" описана так:

```
const handleGoToHomePage = () => {
     props.history.push({
       pathname: "/",
    });
  };
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, решить такое? как я понял, мне нужно сделать отмену api запроса. благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Одним из возможных решений может быть такое:
страница с подробным описанием получает `window.location.pathname` убирает из этого значения свою часть path, и полученную строку использует для `push`

Comment: благодарю за коммент! `<Route path="/pokemon/:pokemonName" component={Pokemon} />`  так описан роут. соответственно url страницы подробного описания  выглядит так: `/pokemon/Pidgeotto`. честно сказать, не очень Вас понял.

Comment: Значит для возврата назад нужно из пути убрать /Pidgeotto

Comment: на главную страницу возвращает с этим проблем нету. проблема состоит в том, что при возврате назад на главную, по новому начинает происходить апи запрос. это значит, что если я ранее добрался до 60го элемента в списке и решил пройти на страницу с подробным описанием, а потом решил уйти назад, то я не вернусь к этому 60му элементу, т.к апи запрос будет выполнятся с нуля.

Comment: тогда на главной странице в state добавь переменную в которой сохраняй количество загруженных/последний загруженный элемент; при выполнении запроса проверяй эту переменную